# List all the images on android device

Tags: android, image

I was trying to list all the images in android device with their paths since 14 hours straight but I wasn't able to .. It keeps giving me "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error.

I don't understand why..

Any help??

```
package com.example.allpicsexample;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

/** * Displays images from an SD card. */ public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/**
 * Cursor used to access the results from querying for images on the SD card.
 */
private Cursor cursor;
/*
 * Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.
 */
private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
    System.out.println("the path is : "+filePath);

}
}
```

and here is the LogCat info:

> 11-14 08:29:01.739: D/AndroidRuntime(16788): Shutting down VM 11-14
>   08:29:01.739: W/dalvikvm(16788): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40018578) 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.allpicsexample/com.example.allpicsexample.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 11-14
>   08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-14
>   08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 11-14
>   08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-14
>   08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 11-14
>   08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-14 08:29:01.749:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16788): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   com.example.allpicsexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   11-14 08:29:01.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16788):  ... 11 more

Here is the 2nd crash log after implementing Abhishek's code

> 11-14 10:00:20.159: D/AndroidRuntime(19266): Shutting down VM 11-14
>   10:00:20.159: W/dalvikvm(19266): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40018578) 11-14 10:00:20.189:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-14 10:00:20.189:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19266): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {com.example.allpicsexample/com.example.allpicsexample.MainActivity}
>   did not call through to super.onCreate() 11-14 10:00:20.189:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1617)
>   11-14 10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   11-14 10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 11-14
>   10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   11-14 10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-14
>   10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 11-14 10:00:20.189:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 11-14
>   10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-14
>   10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 11-14 10:00:20.189:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   11-14 10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 11-14
>   10:00:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a full log? Make sure you didn't forget to declare your activity inside the application's manifest. Cheers!

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 I've pasted the full logcat log, you can check now.. Thanks :)

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 you can also tell me a method to list all the images in an android device....

Comment: I'm not sure how to access everything on the SD card you should have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal. However I think I know why it crashes, you are calling getString on a cursor object that hasn't been initialized. Even if you initialize it before you access it, it will still be empty. Try and replace that and it will prevent the crash.

Comment: If I remove that then there is no point in doing anything..

Comment: I understand what you want to do, all I'm saying is that using a cursor here won't get you there. You need to acquire the path using another way. Try something like "File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);"

Comment: From the code you posted your "cursor" object is always going to be null. Is that all the code?

Comment: @JoeyG yes that is all the code

Comment: https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you have not initialized `cursor` object.
You can use the below code to get path of all the images.

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        //Stores all the images from the gallery in Cursor
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        //Total number of images
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        //Create an array to store path to all the images
        String[] arrPath = new String[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            //Store the path of the image
            arrPath[i]= cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            Log.i("PATH", arrPath[i]);
        }
```

Comment: I'm able to make it work using your code but the app is crashing after sometime?

Comment: @user2990269 Can you post the Logcat?

Comment: I've posted the LobCat info please check the 2nd logcat on my post.

Comment: @user2990269 have you called `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the beginning of `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Does the code which you have shared retrieves all the images from Phone's Internal Memory + External SD Card Memory?

Comment: @user2990269 I think it retrieves images from only external memory. To get images from internal memory the query should be `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);`

Comment: Which like I would have to change in your quoted code? I don't get it.

Comment: @I mean `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);` this query retrieves images from external memory and `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);` this query retrieves images from internal memory.

Comment: @user2990269 no problem..pleasure to help:)

Comment: This only get the images from external directory not the folders inside the sd card. For eg. Whatsapp images will not be retrieved from this.

Comment: @Anuj Pl check the comment above. you need to use INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

Comment: INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is for internal memory. I am talking about external memory but inside the folders. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI gives only images in sd card directly not inside the folders. For eg. /sdcard/image.jpg will be there but /sdcard/abc/image.jpg will not be there.

Comment: Its great! I am using this demo for displaying images: https://dzone.com/articles/displaying-images-sd-card  But as that is based on the thumbnail available in the device, i am not able to get all the images. But then i have try your way. its working fine now. Thanks